# How do you change the amplitude of a specific sine wave after applying the FFT to it?

Tags: fast-fourier-transform

Once I calculate the FFT of a given waveform, how do you change the amplitude of a specific wave or waves before passing it back the IFFT? I understand the imaginary part of the result of the FFT refers to the phase, so would you simply multiply the real part by the factor you want to increase the amplitude by?

Comment: Though there are some shenanigans about normalization, shifting, etc., basically each element of a DFT is a complex coefficient of some complex exponential. The complex magnitude of this coefficient is the amplitude of the corresponding wave, while the complex phase of this coefficient is related to the phase of the corresponding wave (though the exact relationship depends on the wave of course).

Comment: You multiply both real and imaginary by the factor you want to increase the amplitude.